# How to develop generic job in datastage

Tags: datastage

We receive 3 files from source like A B and C ,the file should be in same format,This file used as a input and final output is only one file and jobs are independent so how to develop generic job in datastage and also know the it's is possible to give 3 sequencial files in input

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well from what you described only the filename is probaby different so this should be parameterised.

Build a job with Input file - Transfomer (or any other stages that are needed for your business logic) - Target file.
Make sure the input file name is a job parameter and in the job properties check the box for multiple instance so you can have multiple instances of the job running in parallel (as they are independend)

If you got different structures in the file you have to use RCP (Runtime Column Propagation) in adition to the above.